# How-to mix fixed and percentage heights/width using css without javascript

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to achieve a layout like this:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------
|                                                          |
|  fixed height                                            |
|                                                          |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                      | s |
| takes all the rest available screen height           | c |
| fluid height, not fixed,                             | r | 
| dependent on the screen height                       | o |
|                                                      | l |   
|                                                      | l |
|                                                      | b |
|                                                      | a |
|                                                      | r |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using css and html, without javascript, is it possible? Scrollbar should be completely visible, from top to bottom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/s7FH6/show/ ([edit](http://jsfiddle.net/s7FH6/))

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}
#header {
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px
}
#content {
    background: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the given question! and I must mark it as absolutely correct to the given conditions.

Comment: Bad for me, just as I have read the answer, it popped to my mind that I wanted that the top pane height would not be fixed, but rather its size should be content dependent. Sorry for not mentioning it in the conditions - my bad. I suppose If we add that extra condition - there will be no pure html/css solution. I will start a new question with that extra condition.

Comment: see new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733015/how-to-mix-fixed-and-percentage-height-width-using-css-without-javascript

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve layout like that very simple to be honest just read about divs and some css
heres a example:

```
<div style="width: 604px; height: 405px; border: solid 1px black;">
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; border: solid 1px green;"></div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 74%; border: solid 1px blue;"></div>
</div>
```

dont forget that the width: 604px is only for example just set it to 100% to use all screen size same goes for height.

good luck.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/DCbur/2/

dont forget to vote if you like the answer

Comment: Dear Villi, thanks for answering. Sorry for being not 100% clear. The bottom pane should have flexible height, taking all the rest screen space.

Comment: Willi, am talking about HEIGHT of the bottom pane taking all the rest available SCREEN HEIGHT.

Comment: so just set height: 100%  like i did in my post just edited it

Comment: your example does not respond to the conditions: 1. the height of the bottom pane should take exactly all of the rest available screen height. 2. The bottom pane content should scroll and scrollbars should be completely visible, from top to bottom.